# How to Focus on ListviewItem in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `ListBox` in my application with Ten items, user can see five items at time.
Sometimes I'm selecting items from code and setting focus.

Selecting an item and focusing work perfectly when items are visible on `Form`, but for other non-visible items, I'm unable to set the focus (NOTE: after selecting it is visible to user).

Can anyone help me please?

```
var item = _listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;

if (item != null)
{
   item.Focus();
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the focus ? Post some code..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
_listView.SelectedIndex = index;

var item = _listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;
if (item != null)
{
   item.Focus();
}
```