# How to get virtual Item of databound ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, ui-virtualization

If I have a list of Cars bound to a `ListBox`. 
I now want to implement that the first item is initially focused, additionally I want to implement a full keyboard navigation between the displayed ListBox-items, therefore I need access to the virtually created item controls.

The problem is that `itemStack.Items[i]` returns the `Car` itself and not the `CarEditControl`. How can I get the virtually created item?

```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ItemSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemCollectionTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <custom:Item x:Name="item" Car="{Binding Path=.,Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This answer is for ListView, but the code is essentially the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789408/how-to-focus-on-listviewitem-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks, matt this works. Another question. Is there a way to enumerate all item controls or invoke an event on all item controls?

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: Repost that as answer please.

Comment: @codymanix: No, you need to use some kind of loop (`for`/`foreach`).

Comment: @H.B. As much as I'd love the extra 15 reputation points, I think it's better if we close this as a duplicate so people are directed to the existing answer. I will vote to close.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: Probably not going to reach the needed vote count but one can try.